# Opening character device for reading in parallel by multiple processes on Linux

Tags: keyboard, tty, console, mc, pty

I would like to open a character device e.g. `/dev/tty1` by multiple processes in a way that would not interfere reads between them. I noticed that if one process consumes a byte, no other process would receive it.

**Problem details:**
I'm writing console app on Linux, which requires receiving both: key presses and key releases. I managed already to switch from default terminal mode `K_XLATE` to `K_RAW` mode using `ioctl(fd,KDSKBMODE,K_RAW)` on newly opened `/dev/tty1`. Unfortunately reading from this descriptor resulted in missing bytes as mc tries to intercept `Ctrl+O` key strokes in parallel (to bring its interface on top or hide it back) by reading from same device.

So I tried also to read data from stdin, pseudo terminal pipe created by `mc` (after setting `/dev/tty` to `K_RAW` mode). It almost worked, except now I have collision of `Ctrl+O` character code `0x0F` with Tab key scancode (also `0x0F`).

I'm looking for solution to that interference problem in a way not requiring more privileges than `cap_sys_tty_config`, so accessing `/dev/input` in order to read keyboard directly is not way to go for me.

Comment: So you want to buffer bytes for all processes that read e.g. `/dev/tty1`? What should happen if 10 processes happily read kilobytes of characters per second, while the 11th is really slow, and reads one character per hour? Should you buffer all for the 11th process? When does that buffer overflow?

Comment: Yeah, that would cause problem, but such problem already exists at the writer end, even with a single reader, writer is simply blocked if too much data is written, right? Same thing OS could do if a reader is too much ahead of other readers. Do you confirm it is not possible on Linux?

Comment: You can't block the "writer" (which, in the end, is the guy at the keyboard, or the other computer on a serial line), because hardware events are the "writer" as far as Linux is concerned. The point I was trying to make is that your configuration is not trivial, and you have to make design decisions. That's why it's not in-built. And anything is possible, you just have to sit down and make it if it's not there already. E.g. you can use `tee`, or rewrite the `tee` code if you want different design decisions, or pass through terminal ioctl's etc.